# Displaying file name extensions in html using external js

Tags: javascript, file-extension

I am trying to display the file name extensions using html and an external javascript but my website remains blank. I got this example code from another stackoverflow answer but I am unable to get it to work. Shouldn't the extension of my variables be shown when I call the function in my html like such?

```
<script>getExtension(file1);</script>
```

js

```
var file1 = "index.php";
var file2 = "test.js";
function getExtension(filename) {
    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, filename.length) || filename;
}
```

Comment: You are getting the extension correctly but you don't write it to your output anywhere. You could try for example `document.write(getExtension(file1));`

Comment: Because you are printing or writing it on the page. instead of returning the extension use document.write and you will see the extension.

For more details please go through the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: show where your are trying it should work

Comment: Thank you Stephan that worked. I tried document.write but must have messed up the code somewhere. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the extension correctly but you don't write it to your output anywhere. There are different approaches to output the value, here are two possibilities:

1. [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)
   The `Document.write()` method writes a string of text to a document stream. But be careful, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open`, which will **clear the document**.

```js
var file1 = "index.php";
var file2 = "test.js";
function getExtension(filename) {
    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, filename.length) || filename;
}
// This will add "php" to the document
document.write(getExtension(file1));

// This will clear the document and replace it with "js" - added 1 second delay to visualize it
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(  'document.write(getExtension(file2))', 1000 );
}
```

```html
<h1>My content</h1>
```

2. [`createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) + [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
   You can also create a text node and append it to your body. Of course you could also create any other element and add it wherever you want.

```js
var file1 = "index.php";
var file2 = "test.js";
function getExtension(filename) {
    return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.')+1, filename.length) || filename;
}

// Create a text node
var t = document.createTextNode(getExtension(file1));
// Append it to the body
document.body.appendChild(t);
```

```html
<h1>My content</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!